# How can I use Google Voice with an iPad? (I'm getting a "cannot open page" error)

Tags: google-voice, ipad

When trying to call a number using Google Voice on an iPad, I get the following error:

> Cannot Open Page
>   Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.

Is there any way to place a call through Google Voice while using an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that that page is currently broken and only works on iPhones. It doesn't work on iPods or iPads. You should use one of Google's other interfaces for placing calls.

There are several options:

1. https://www.google.com/voice/m: The currently broken page that only works on the iPhone. This page looks the best on an iPad. However, not being able to place calls is a real show stopper. This is the only one of the 3 options that has a home screen icon.
2. https://www.google.com/voice/: The desktop version of the site, which works on the iPad, but has UI glitches, since it obviously wasn't meant to be used on an iPad.
3. https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/m: The old mobile interface of Google Voice. There are no UI glitches, but it doesn't look that good either, since it is obviously formatted for a mobile phone. Placing calls does work on an iPad though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an app like [GV Mobile +](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gv-mobile/id392608246?mt=8), which, even though it's for iPhone, works just fine on the iPad.